What does "Nor our strong sorrow, upon the foot of motion" mean?
After the murder of Duncan in Macbeth, his two sons, Malcolm and Donalbain, have this discussion after being informed of the murder of their father:

Malcolm [Aside to Donalbain]
Why do we hold our tongues,
That most may claim this argument for ours?
Donalbain [Aside to Malcolm]
What should be spoken here, where our fate,
Hid in an auger-hole, may rush, and seize us?
Let's away;
Our tears are not yet brew'd.
Malcolm [Aside to Donalbain]
Nor our strong sorrow
Upon the foot of motion.

I'm not quite sure what that last line from Malcolm is supposed to mean. The previous lines evidently talk about how they need time to process the murder of their father, and that they're worried about what fate will decide for them — i.e., will they be murdered too? Coronated? Malcolm is, after all, the Prince of Cumberland.
But what does "...strong sorrow, upon the foot of motion" mean? The "strong sorrow" evidently has to do with the death of Duncan, but what does this mean in the context of "upon the foot of motion"?

Malcolm and Donalbain are agreeing that they need first to get to safety, and only then to take steps to mitigate their grief by identifying the perpetrators and bringing them to justice. The brothers are too stunned by their father's murder to have any immediate, overt response. Their reaction is rather to freeze in shock. The protestations of Macduff, Banquo, and the Macbeths therefore seem insincere to them. They also realize that they are themselves in grave danger and must flee at once, without taking any time to grieve.
Donalbain therefore says that they are not yet ready to cry: Our tears are not yet brew'd. Malcolm agrees, saying that their strong sorrow is not yet upon the foot of motion, i.e., ready to move them. Malcolm's words signify on the one hand, the shock that keeps the princes from displays of sorrow (they seem as yet unmoved) and on the other, the imperative to get moving (to shake off their immobility and foot it), to leave Inverness and Scotland right away. Their subsequent dialogue, when Malcolm announces his intention to make for England and Donalbain his for Ireland, makes this clear:

Malcolm
What will you do? Let's not consort with them.
To show an unfelt sorrow is an office
Which the false man does easy. I'll to England.
Donalbain
To Ireland, I; our separated fortune
Shall keep us both the safer.

Malcolm's words are also an implicit rebuke to Macbeth, who has been upon the foot of motion, moved quickly, already. Immediately upon Duncan's death becoming known, he has killed Duncan's men, falsely claiming that they are the assassins. By contrast, Malcolm says that he and Donalbain should not translate their sorrow into any action to avenge Duncan just yet: the situation is too fraught.

"Nor our strong sorrow / Upon the foot of motion." means that their powerful grief has not yet set in motion (any) action". The missing auxiliary is "are" from the previous sentence ("are not yet brew'd").
A. R. Braunmuller (The New Cambridge Shakespeare, Cambridge University Press, 1997, page 156) thinks that the lines "probably include a revision of an earlier version of this scene" and refers to page 259–260 in the "Textual analysis" where the theory of revision of the First Folio is discussed. (See also the older question Do we have any solid evidence for how much material Middleton contributed to Macbeth?)
The lines are examples of some of the lineation problems in the play, i.e. the question whether the compositors of the First Folio set some lines of prose as verse or the other way round. Nicholas Brooke (The Oxford Shakespeare, Oxford University Press, 1999, page 220) notes that the arrangement of these lines in the First Folio was caused by space problems and adds,

It is possible that these lines were an afterthought, since they first articulate the suspicions that are previously only implicit in the dialogue, and F has similar problems with Malcolm and Donalbain in ll. 132–8.

("F" stands for First Folio, which contains the first printed version of Macbeth, since the play had not previously been published in quarto.)
